# Playing encrypted files on Android

Tags: android, media-player

I need to develop application for Android which decrypts audio and video files saved on SDCARD
and plays them without saving on SDCARD or on phone.
Is there any way to do using standard Android MediaPlayern class?
Thanks, Costa.

Comment: This is my solution. Tested so far on MP3 files up to 10MB without a hitch. https://gist.github.com/frostymarvelous/26ac6cba11bf50e591a4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to build HTTP server on the phone and play the files using the server.
There the link to server I used (and it worked good):
http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/10/simple-http-server-java.html

Thanks!

Comment: I confirm that a stream delivered by a local server is the way to avoid a transient unsafe storage. But note that the server is not so simple as that ; for instance, it has to support the Range header.

Comment: the link is redirecting to different site